# How to change from fragment to another fragment instantly control by one of the fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a navigation drawer which I would like to press the button in the list view and change the fragment on the right side instantly. How can I do that? Why my code doesn't work?

Here is my code:

`DrawerFragment.class`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DrawerFragment extends Fragment {

private static ListView mSelectionListView;
private ImageView mUserIcon;
private TextView mUserName;

//region (Widgets) Declaration
NonScrollListView mNewsListView, mELeaveListView, mEClaimListView, mEAttendanceListView;
//endregion

//DrawerFragmentListener drawerFragmentListener;


//endregion


Fragment mFragment;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
ExpenseClaimPageFragment expenseClaimPageFragment;
ClaimFormPageFragment claimFormPageFragment;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_drawer_fragment, container, false);


    expenseClaimPageFragment = new ExpenseClaimPageFragment();
    claimFormPageFragment = new ClaimFormPageFragment();



    mEClaimListView = (NonScrollListView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_fragment_eClaim_selection);

    ArrayList<DrawerSelectionEClaimResult> selectionEClaimResults = GetDrawerSelectionEClaimResult();
    mEClaimListView.setAdapter(new CustomDrawerSelectionEClaimBaseAdapter(getActivity(), selectionEClaimResults));


    mEClaimListView.setOnItemClickListener(mEClaimListViewOnItemClick);

    return view;
    }

public ArrayList<DrawerSelectionEClaimResult> GetDrawerSelectionEClaimResult() {

    ArrayList<DrawerSelectionEClaimResult> results = new ArrayList<>();

    DrawerSelectionEClaimResult dsecr = new DrawerSelectionEClaimResult();
    dsecr.setSelection("Expenses Claim Entry");
    dsecr.setDrawable(R.drawable.expenseclaim);
    results.add(dsecr);

    dsecr = new DrawerSelectionEClaimResult();
    dsecr.setSelection("Expenses Claim Form");
    dsecr.setDrawable(R.drawable.expenseclaim);
    results.add(dsecr);

    return results;
}

    public NonScrollListView.OnItemClickListener mEClaimListViewOnItemClick = new NonScrollListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                mFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragment = new ExpenseClaimPageFragment();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MainPageFrameLayout, mFragment);
                mFragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                mFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragment = new ClaimFormPageFragment();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MainPageFrameLayout, mFragment);
                mFragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
        }

        }
    };
  }
```

`Main.xml`

```
<!--Main Content View (Expense Claim Page Content)-->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainPageFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.sample.flexsystem.expenseclaimapplication.ExpenseClaimPageFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_expenseclaim_page" />
</FrameLayout>
<!--Navigation Drawer View-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLin"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:name="com.sample.flexsystem.expenseclaimapplication.DrawerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_drawer_fragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have no idea why my code doesn't work, what is the main code to replace the fragment to another? I know that I need a layout to save a fragment inside and use replace() method to handle it, but it didn't work. Is there anything wrong of my code?

**I think I can not replace the fragment from another fragment since fragment doesn't communicate to each other right?**

**UPDATE 1**

`Main Activity class`

```
    import android.content.Intent;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
  import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuInflater;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;


  public class ExpenseClaimPage extends AppCompatActivity implements           DrawerFragment.DrawerFragmentListener{

DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
Fragment mFragment;

@Override
public void setPosition(int position)
{
    switch(position)
    {
        case 0:
            mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            mFragment = new ExpenseClaimPageFragment();
            mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MainPageFrameLayout, mFragment);
            mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            mFragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;

        case 1:
            mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            mFragment = new ClaimFormPageFragment();
            mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MainPageFrameLayout, mFragment);
            mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            mFragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
    }
}









//region onCreate
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
}
//endregion


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Why u add fragment2 inside MainPageFrameLayout, i don't see where it used. Try remove this fragment out xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `main.xml`, the main content:

```
Main Content View (Expense Claim Page Content)
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainPageFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="ExpenseClaimPageFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_expenseclaim_page" />
</FrameLayout>
```

You cant replace fragment which is added by using `xml`. Therefore, I suggest that you should add your `ExpenseClaimPageFragment` manually when the activity is created. After that, you can replace it with another fragment easily.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by add my ExpenseClaimPageFragment manually when the activity is created? How can I add the fragment to my main activity?

Comment: @JohnnyCheuk If i'm not misunder stand, the default view of your activity is `ExpenseClaimPageFragment`. If so, instead of declaring it in xml as above `xml`, you can add it in onCreate right? you can do it by: mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.simple_fragment, new ExpenseClaimPageFragment() ).commit();

Comment: the default view of my activity is not expenseclaimpagefragment. I will just put my mainactivity activity right away

Comment: @JohnnyCheuk anyway, just put your `MainPageFrameLayout` as an empty `FrameLayout`. It will allow you to change your `fragment` inside it. Now, you cant change because of its child fragment.